# Как в Delphi узнать количество занимаемой приложением оперативной памяти?

Tags: windows, delphi, память, delphi-xe5

Во время работы приложения по обработке больших объемов данных, хочу стартовать отдельный фоновый поток и мониторить объем занимаемой приложением оперативной памяти. По аналогии с тем, как Task Manager показывает выделенную приложению память. Каким методом/функцией можно это узнать из работающей программы? Предпочтительно, если это будет RTL, а не WinAPI.

Методика подсчета (считать ли память используемых DLL, учитывать ли выгрузку в swap, и т.п.) на самом деле не принципиальна. Меня больше интересует динамика на масштабах десятков-сотен мегабайт. Поэтому предпочтение будет отдано наиболее простому способу измерения, а не наиболее "точному".

ОС Windows, приложение x32.

([похожий вопрос на англ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437683/))

Comment: Есть некоторая сложность с формализацией понятия "объем занимаемой приложением оперативной памяти". Память, выделенная под загруженные приложением dll занимается им или нет? ОС выделяет ее один раз под все приложения, использующие одну библиотеку. А участок выделенного виртуального пространства адресов, который еще не привязан к физической странице - занят или нет?

Comment: Для моих целей, это на самом деле не принципиально. В общем случае все способы будут примерно совпадать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uses .., psAPI, Windows;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pmc: PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS;
  cb: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  cb := SizeOf(_PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS);
  GetMem(pmc, cb);
  pmc^.cb := cb;
  if GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), pmc, cb) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add( FloatToStr(pmc^.WorkingSetSize/1024) + ' KB');
    Memo1.Lines.Add( FloatToStr(pmc^.PagefileUsage/1024) + ' KB');
  end;
  FreeMem(pmc);
end;
```

`PagefileUsage/1024` — поле «виртуальная память».
`WorkingSetSize/1024` — очень близкое значение к полю «память».

`WorkingSetSize` — это рабочий набор, сумма памяти занимаемой приложением и в user mode и в kernel mode, т.е. включая всю память отведённую для хранения информации о программе в системе (объект-процесс, объект-поток, хендлы и т.д.).

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный менеджер память Delphi предоставляет функцию [GetMemoryManagerState](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.GetMemoryManagerState) которая показывает выделение памяти средствами Delphi.

Также на сайте есть [пример ее использования](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/RTL.UsageTracker_Sample)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, я бы проверил на всякий случай, а не Win95/Win98 ли у нас. Плюс, можно воспользоваться OpenProcess вместо GetCurrentProcess (хотя, признаю, что [это медленнее](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess)). Как-то так:

```
function GetProgramRAMUsed:int64;
var
  MainHandle: THandle;
  pmc: PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS;
  cb: Integer;
begin
  if Win32Platform = 2 then
     begin
          MainHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, false, GetCurrentProcessID);
          cb := SizeOf(_PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS);
          GetProcessMemoryInfo(MainHandle, @pmc, cb);
          Result:=pmc.WorkingSetSize;
          CloseHandle(MainHandle);
     end
   else Result:=-1;
end;
```